# Selecting a select list based on post request

Tags: php, html

please, i'm somewhat new with php bear with me.
I have a selectbox...

```
<select name="criteria">
        <option value="1">Student ID</option>
        <option value="2">Firstname </option>
        <option value="3">Lastname</option>
        <option value="6">All</option>
    </select>

    <input name="searchvalue" type="text">
    <input name="search" type="submit" value="Search">
```

When i search with a particular option, after the post request, the selected option usually defaults to Student ID. But i want it to still remain the option i searched with. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest I'd adjust your select code just a little bit to allow for a bit more dynamic editing..

```
<?php 
$options = array('1'=>'Student ID', '2'=>'Firstname', '3'=>'Lastname', '6'=>'All');     
?>

<select name="criteria">

<?php 
foreach($options as $key=>$value){
    $addtItem = '';
    if(isset($_POST['criteria']) && $_POST['criteria']==$key){
        $addtItem = 'selected="selected"';
    }
    echo('<option '.addtItem.' value="'.key.'">'.$value.'</option>');
}

?>

</select>
```

This way you can quickly add more values without a ton of repeat code..

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="criteria">
    <option value="1" <?php if ($_POST["criteria"] == 1) echo "SELECTED"; ?>>Student ID</option>
    <option value="2" <?php if ($_POST["criteria"] == 2) echo "SELECTED"; ?>>Firstname </option>
    <option value="3" <?php if ($_POST["criteria"] == 3) echo "SELECTED"; ?>>Lastname</option>
    <option value="6" <?php if ($_POST["criteria"] == 6) echo "SELECTED"; ?>>All</option>
</select>
```

Really ugly, but that works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the `$_POST` array and select the corresponding select item

```
<?php 
$criteria = isset($_POST['criteria']) ? $_POST['criteria']: 0; 
?>
<select name="criteria">
    <option value="1" <?php echo ($criteria == '1') ? 'selected="selected"': ''; ?>>Student ID</option>
    <option value="2" <?php echo ($criteria == '2') ? 'selected="selected"': ''; ?>>Firstname </option>
    <option value="3" <?php echo ($criteria == '3') ? 'selected="selected"': ''; ?>>Lastname</option>
    <option value="6" <?php echo ($criteria == '6') ? 'selected="selected"': ''; ?>>All</option>
</select>
```

Comment: yea, from a first look, i know this works. I love your implementation. Thanks.